# Injecting a Bean Instance Returned by Factory class

Tags: dependency-injection

I am working on a piece of code wherein I have a Spring Bean say B.java.
The constructor for this Bean depends upon 2 arguments.
Additionally this Spring Bean has another Spring Bean, say C.java injected to it.
I have a factory class say Factory.java that has a getInstance() Method that returns a new object of type B.java depending upon the passed in constructor parameters.
Now I want to inject the returned instance of class B in another class, say C.java which is a Spring Bean with all its properties instantiated i.e the reference to C.java as well.

Can somebody please help in creating context.xml files for this.

Following is a rough prototype of the class structures:

```
public class B{

private String arg1;

private String arg2;

private C c;

public void setC(C c){
    this.c=c;
}

B(String arg1, String arg2){
    this.arg1 = arg1;
    this.arg2 = arg2;
}
}

................................

public class Factory{

private String arg1;
private String arg2;

public B getInstance(){
    return new B(arg1, arg2);
}

}
...............................

public class C{
@Autowired
private B b;

@Autowired
private D d;
}
```

Thanks